# How to enable unmanaged code debugging in metro

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

how do I enable unmanaged debugging in visual studio in Win8 developer preview.

I have a WinRT component dll that is being called from a C# application.

When I try to call the component dll, it seems to work but does not hit the breakpoints and I am unable to step into it. in the C# app properties, the Debug tab does not seem to have the "Enable Unmanaged DEbugging option". In the WinRT dll, the debugger is set to "Both Native and Managed DEbugger".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>true</EnableUnmanagedDebugging> in the propertygroup does not help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the developer preview to verify. If you are using visual studio express, I don't believe this is supported. Mixed mode debugging is working for me in  Visual Studio Ultimate on the Consumer Preview without issue though.